# What happens if DBI::mysql_enable_utf8 was not properly set?

Tags: mysql, perl, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I missed this statement and I ended up with funny characters in the database:

[mysql_enable_utf8 flag documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.038/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#mysql_enable_utf8)

> Additionally, turning on this flag tells MySQL that incoming data
>   should be treated as UTF-8. This will only take effect if used as part
>   of the call to connect(). If you turn the flag on after connecting,
>   you will need to issue the command SET NAMES utf8 to get the same
>   effect.

This is a part of the code:

```
use strict;
use utf8;
use open qw/:std :utf8/;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("...", $user, $pass) or die_report($@);
my $query;

$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1; #this caused the problem, because it was added after the connect() statement.

$dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE `$database`.`$table` (`id` INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT `response` MEDIUMTEXT) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci")->execute or die($@);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$response = $ua->get('http://example.com')->decoded_content;


$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `$mysql_database`.`$mysql_table` (`id`, `response`) VALUES (?, ?)");
$query->execute($id, $response);
```

I need to understand what happens to `$response` when it is inserted in mysql and how to revert the damage.
Does it get double encoded? Can I fix it in a smart way?

Comment: Tip: `"\`$database\`.\`$table\`"` should be `$dbh->quote_identifier($database, $table)`.

Comment: Please provide `HEX(\`response\`)` of corrupted data.

Comment: @ikegami, I think the original table is "poisoned", and that's why I'm getting this. Maybe some package that I wrote did not have `use utf8` or something like that, because this is what I have:  _Before table ALTER:_
**Entry 1:** **SzabÃ³nÃ©**
`537A6162C383C2B30000006EC383C2A9000000`
**Entry 2:** **Szabóné**
`537A6162C3B36EC3A9`  _After table ALTER:_ **Entry 1:** **Szabóné**
`537A6162C3B30000006EC3A9000000`
**Entry 2:** **Szab**
`537A6162`

Comment: LE: I meant to say: Maybe some package that I wrote did not have `use utf8` and I've added it later, or something like that...

Comment: Where do ask those NUL come from? This is corrupted by far more than a bad `mysql_enable_utf8` flag

Comment: Are you saying you have one row that contains `537A6162C383C2B30000006EC383C2A9000000` and one that contains `537A6162C3B36EC3A9` and that both should be `Szabóné`? If so, not all rows are corrupt. `537A6162C3B36EC3A9` is what you should have.

Comment: Yes they should both have been `Szabóné`, not all rows and corrupt [ _because the code ran in stages, and at some point I  might have "fixed" it by accident with an `use utf8;` or something that changes the encoding, without realizing at that point_ ], and `537A6162C3B36EC3A9` is what I should have had.

Answer (score 1):

If `Encode::is_utf8($response)` was true, and if the connection's encoding (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character_set_client"`) was set to `latin1`, the following will do the trick:

```
UPDATE TheTable
   SET response = CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(response USING latin1) USING BINARY) USING utf8)
```

---

You can view MySQL strings as bytes with an associated encoding, where `BINARY` is a special encoding. The following explains how conversions (whether by `CONVERT` or from storing into a field) work:

1. Converting from a non-binary encoding to another non-binary encoding converts the underlying bytes.
2. Converting from a non-binary encoding to binary simply changes the encoding associated with the bytes to binary (without changing the bytes).
3. Converting from binary to a non-binary encoding simply changes the encoding associated with the bytes to new encoding (without changing the bytes).

So, if `response` contains the three characters `â™¡`, the following happens:

```
C3 A2 E2 84 A2 C2 A1 [utf8] (â™¡)      `response` has an utf8 collation
     |
     |  CONVERT(_ USING latin1)        Changes how the string is encoded (as per #1)
     v
E2 99 A1 [latin1] (â™¡)
     |
     |  CONVERT(_ USING BINARY)        Changes the associated encoding (as per #2)
     v
E2 99 A1 [BINARY]
     |
     |  CONVERT(_ USING utf8)          Changes the associated encoding (as per #3)
     v
E2 99 A1 [utf8] (♡)
     |
     |  UPDATE SET `response` = _      Changes how the string is encoded (as per #1)
     v
E2 99 A1 [utf8] (♡)                    `response` has an utf8 collation
```

Technically, since `response` has an `utf8` collation, you could forgo the outermost `CONVERT`.

Comment: Tip: Make a backup first!

Comment: before asking the question, I've tried the following on a duplicate table: `ALTER TABLE d MODIFY description TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1;
ALTER TABLE d MODIFY description TEXT CHARACTER SET binary;
ALTER TABLE d MODIFY description TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;` but I've discovered that some entries got chopped after the following character `"Ã"`[ _this character was present in the original table, after the ALTER of the table, the entry got chopped after this character_ ]. So I thought that I should better ask what really happens in the background, before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

`53 7A 61 62 C383 C2B3` is "double-encoded".  One cure is

```
CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('537A6162C383C2B3')
        USING utf8) USING latin1)) USING utf8) --> 'Szabó'
```

Or, more relevantly:

```
CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('SzabÃƒÂ³' USING latin1))
        USING utf8mb4) USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4) --> 'Szabó'
```

Or, more simply:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(col USING latin1)) USING utf8);
```

See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) and search for "double".
See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#other_computer_languages) and search for "Perl".
[*Fixes for various cases*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases).